# How to make secure request to REST, having signed Certificate with Public key, and Private Key generated with Certificate Request

Tags: c#, rest, https, request

I need to make https request to RESTAPI. Before, i made Certificate Request and private key, using OpenSSL. After, my Certificate Request had been signed by provider and i took certificate. Thus i have certificate and private key.
The question: How to make secure request using this certificate, private key and .net features.
Now i provide code, that i already wrote with help of my intuition(note: i used BouncyCustle to read pem files):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        X509Certificate certificate = getCertificate("c:/xxx/certificate.pem");
        AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = getPrivateKey("c:/xxx/key.pem");

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = prepareWebRequest("https://xxxx", 
                "GET", certificate, privateKey);

        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
        Console.Write("Stack trace: {0}", e.StackTrace);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static X509Certificate getCertificate(string pathToSertificate)
{
    X509Certificate certificateBouncyCustle;

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToSertificate, FileMode.Open))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        var pemReader = new PemReader(streamReader);
        certificateBouncyCustle = (X509Certificate)pemReader.ReadObject();
    }

    return certificateBouncyCustle;
}

private static AsymmetricKeyParameter getPrivateKey(string pathToPrivateKey)
{
    AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey;

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(pathToPrivateKey, FileMode.Open))
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
        var pemReader = new PemReader(streamReader);
        privateKey = ((AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pemReader.ReadObject()).Private;
    }

    return privateKey;
}

private static HttpWebRequest prepareWebRequest(string url, 
        string method, 
        X509Certificate certificate, 
        AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    httpWebRequest.Method = method;
    httpWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(certificate));                   
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml;charset=UTF8";                        

    return httpWebRequest;
}
```